# Why do methods and types impose different constraints on variance?

Tags: scala, covariance

I'm puzzled why scala treats `def` and `type` differently when counting variance constraints?

I tried to break my wall of text and factored my return type into a separate type declaration, and got a variance error immediately. Here is a minimized example:

```
class Bad[+A] {
  type Check[B >: A] = Bad[B]
  def check[B >: A] : Check[B] = this
}
```

which fails:

```
covariant.scala:2: error: covariant type A occurs in invariant position in type  >: A of type B
  type Check[B >: A] = Bad[B]
             ^
one error found
```

Still, it works fine without the extra type declaration:

```
class Good[+A] {
  def check[B >: A]: Good[B] = this
}

class Ugly[+A] {
  type Check[B >: A @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance] = Ugly[B]
  def check[B >: A] : Check[B] = this
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because as soon as the type member `Check` escapes to the outside,
it can immediately appear both in co- and contravariant positions in functions and 
methods:

```
class Bad[+A] {
  type Check[B]
}

class B
class A extends B

val bad: Bad[A] = ???
import bad._

def hypotheticalMethodSomewhereOutside1(c: Check[B]) = ???
def hypotheticalMethodSomewhereOutside2(i: Int): Check[B] = ???
```

The crucial difference to the `[B >: A]` type argument in the *method* `check`

```
def check[B >: A]: Good[B] = this
```

is that the single method `check` *is under your control*, you can guarantee that 
it does not use `A` in a not-covariant position.

In contrast to that, the type member `Check` can appear in infinitely many other methods 
in both co- and contravariant positions, and *those methods are not under your control*, 
so you cannot prohibit the usage of `Check` in positions in which `A` appears not-covariant,
e.g. you cannot prevent `hypotheticalMethodSomewhereOutsideN` from the example above to
be defined by someone else.

---

Note that the presence of the method `check` is not necessary for your `Bad` example to fail:

```
// error: covariant type A occurs in invariant position in type  >: A of type B
class Bad[+A] {
  type Check[B >: A] = Bad[B]
  // def check[B >: A] : Check[B] = this
}
```

However, if you *hide* the member type `Check` from everyone 
(really *everyone*, including even other instances of same class, that is, 
with the extremely reclusive `private[this]` access modifier):

```
class Bad[+A] {
  private[this] type Check[B >: A] = Bad[B]
}
```

it compiles just nicely.

The `private[this]` solves the problem, because with this modifier, only the methods 
inside the class have to be inspected, no hypothetical methods somewhere outside 
have to be taken into consideration:

```
class Ok[+A] {
  private[this] type Check[B >: A] = Ok[B]
  def ok[B >: A](c: Check[B]): Unit = ???
  def alsoOk[B >: A]: Check[B] = ???
}
```

Note that the above can be written just as

```
class Good[+A] {
  type Check[+B] = Good[B]
  def ok[B >: A](c: Check[B]): Unit = ???
  def alsoOk[B >: A]: Check[B] = ???
}
```

which makes sense only if the type constructor `Good` has way more arguments than `Check`.

Comment: I need the type in children, so protected (inside sealed trait and final classes) are the most powerful restriction I could force on the type. It looks that I should resort to the ugly way

Comment: As the last remark in my question... *insinuates*, it's not entirely clear why a member type with a covariant argument wouldn't do what you want, it is not obvious from your question. Might be an XY-problem, I've explained only the `Y`, and I don't know what the actual `X` is...

Comment: Well it may insinuate, but the target is not you, it addresses the scala language, which could not process sealed and final classes accurately.

Comment: @ayvango Huh, what, who is which target of what? I'm not a JVM, so I can't be a `-target` for anything useful, I think you misunderstood my last comment somehow... I just wanted to say that since I don't know what you wanted to achieve with a declaration like `type Check[B >: A]`, I cannot tell you how to do it better. See also [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Your answer was very useful. It shows that the compiler behaviour is not glitch but systematic. So I need to accept it as is. And either redesign code or take ugly approach which I learned from the standard library